# Intentionally bumping

Tags: discussion

Intentionally "bumping" is generally frowned upon, for good reason. However, look at this circumstance: [That which doesn't kill you](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/19023/that-which-doesnt-kill-you). In my edit, I'm kind of putting it out there that I might do this again. Having done it once, I've learned a few things. Next time I want to leave the question "active" as an invitation to respond for at least a week. "Accepting" an answer is kind of a gold star. I'm not adverse to using bounty points the same way. I can't give them a cookie, but I can give them rep points! :)

So I'm inclined to "bump" questions like this. Is there a better way to handle it?

Comment: I think bounties are meant for this. PS: I really like the idea behind these questions, but I have to say that the answer to this one was an easy google away!

Comment: True, but who am to suggest that using Google is a bad thing? Spoken like any good teacher though, "keep it up!" Eventually you *will* get slam dunked :).

Comment: I didn't want to sound negative or say anything against googling an answer. BTW, the picture of getting slam dunked is beautiful. Wordplays are fun! :)

Comment: Now that I've seen MaulikV's answer I'm getting even more attracted to this sort of question. I find the aspect of challenging learners to contribute particularly valuable, both to the site and to them.

Comment: So, the question stands. How do I(we) do it? Is it OK to intentionally bump?

Comment: Imagine another answer. This one is mangled beyond all human comprehension. You look at it and all you can do is tilt your head. So here comes the author. You hold his hand, little by little, bit by bit, you walk him through difficult phrases. He gets there and answers the question well. Really, did you have a better thing to do today?

Comment: @StoneyB STONEY!!!!! That is soooo cool :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nico's got it; this is what bounties are for. If a question goes unanswered (or unsatisfactorily answered) for a long period of time and you are interested in the answer, add a bounty. This draws more attention to the question and further incentivizes answerers. Editing solely to bump a question is generally frowned upon. Bounties are great for community participation, though!

Comment: Yep, I'm convinced. This one isn't going beautifully, but I'll try it again before I give up on the concept. No question, a bounty is the way to handle it. My big mistake was to "accept" an answer so quickly. When I do it again there will be a bounty right away, and I won't accept an answer until it's time to award the bounty. *One More Time With Feeling!*

Comment: Can bounty points be split?

Comment: Nope. You have to award the bounty to one answer. But you can up vote both, and the accept can go to a different one if that makes sense in a certain case.

Comment: In the case of the "That which doesn't kill you" question, it will be up to StoneyB to award the bounty, right? Since he offered it?

Comment: @jolene Yes. But I think you can add another bounty of your own (and you could each select a different answer to award it to). If you can't add a bounty now, you can do one after Stoney's is complete. I've seen multiple bounties awarded on MSO questions before.

Comment: Perhaps next time. This question has been a nice steep learning curve. :)

Comment: But be warned: you have to spend more points on each successive bounty!